# What is a equivalent of Delphi FillChar in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

What is the C# equivalent of Delphi's `FillChar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand FillChar correctly, it sets all elements of an array to the same value, yes?

In which case, unless the value is 0, you probably have to loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) {
    arr[i] = value;
}
```

For setting the values to the type's 0, there is `Array.Clear`

Obviously, with the loop answer you can stick this code in a utility method if you need... for example, as an extension method:

```
public static void FillChar<T>(this T[] arr, T value) {...}
```

Then you can use:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
//...
data.FillChar(7);
```

If you *absolutely* must have block operations, then `Buffer.BlockCopy` can be used to blit data between array locatiosn - for example, you could write the first chunk, then blit it a few times to fill the bulk of the array.

Comment: FillChar fills a structure (any one) with a given length with the same value. It is not the most descriptive name in the Delphi library but is has been around for a long time.

Comment: @Gamecat - to overwrite *any* structure, you would probably need to use unsafe code and simply write over it... the question would be: why?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to fill a byte array with zeros (as that's what FillChar is mostly used for in Delphi).

.NET is guaranteed to initialize all the values in a byte array to zero on creation, so generally FillChar in .NET isn't necessary.

So saying:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

will create a buffer of 1024 zero bytes.

If you need to zero the bytes after the buffer has been used, you could consider just discarding your byte array and declaring a new one (that's if you don't mind having the GC work a bit harder cleaning up after you).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in C#:

```
String text = "hello";
text.PadRight(10, 'h').ToCharArray();
```